# magento cli error after module installation by composer

Tags: magento2, module, error, composer, cli

i use magetno 2.2.3 . the bin/magento cli is  working fine until I add a module by composer require [module name]  --ignore-platform-reqs.after that it gives me  a long term error :

[image]

so how should I add a module to Magento by the composer and don't get this error while using PHP  bin/magento ... after that? and where is the problem of bin/magento with composer require ....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you are using composer 1 if not then download composer.phar file and run `php composer.phar install` and check if it runs smoothly. If this is done then run composer command `php composer.phar require [module name]` if you want then you can use --no-update followed by your command.

Happy Coding

Comment: thanks a lot. the problem was my composer version. but why Magento doesn't accept composer version 2 for installing modules?